How to do parallel function calling in Autogen?
Using the example from OpenAI to specify my need: "For example, the model may call functions to get the weather in 3 different locations at the same time, which will result in a message with 3 function calls in the tool_calls array."
Imagine I have a tool function weather() and 3 cities. I don't want to use 3 rounds of conversation to do the function call; instead, I want to simultaneously execute this process in the same round.
I have learnt about the parallel function calling of OpenAI API as in https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling .
I have known that Autogen support this feature as in https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/issues/589 .
I just can't figure out how to integrate the two, since function calling seems to be something interior, and all I can modify in autogen is the specific tool function.
